# Unable to install player module with npm

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install the following node module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/player

Upon trying to install it with the command

```
npm install player
```

I get the following wall of error outputs:

```
C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots>npm install player

> lame@1.2.3 install C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\lame
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\lame>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\lame
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:lame@1.2.3 lame@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:lame@1.2.3 Exit status 1

> speaker@0.2.6 install C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\speaker
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\speaker>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\speaker
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:speaker@0.2.6 speaker@0.2.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:speaker@0.2.6 Exit status 1

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots
└── (empty)

npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\utf-8-validate\package.json'
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots\node_modules\bufferutil\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON PinkstarTVBots No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON PinkstarTVBots No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON PinkstarTVBots No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON PinkstarTVBots No license field.
npm ERR! code 1

C:\Users\AbfalterJakob\MEGA\Projekte\PinkstarTVBots>
```

Im unable to figure out from this errors what's causing the problem. I tried already to install node-gyp, which worked, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the version that you are using/installed in your system is not supported.

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
```

Try to install a version of Python lower than 3.0.0 and greater than 2.5.0. It should solve the issue.

In the GitHub page of [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) they recommend **Python v2.7**

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error, but now I got another one namely that it can't find `VCBuild.exe`, even though I have .NET Framework installed ...

Comment: Seems that you need more than .Net installed in your System. Could you check the following links? [https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) (It is a link to the github page of node-gyp and it describes the process to install it on Windows) and [https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-158163655](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-158163655)